# SQL - Pivoting where the rows of one table are the column titles of another

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm looking to create a table (shown below) more in the form of a matrix, where the column titles are variables.

@ACTable AS ACT

[image]

@WCTable AS WCT

[image]

The temp table, derived from @ProductionTable AS PT

[image]

The output I'm looking for looks like this. Essentially I want the ACT.AC running as column titles, the WCT.WC running down, and counting how many were ActFin on Nov 6th. The colour shows the matching associations. I'll coalesce the rest after, not too concerned about NULLs or 0s.

[image]

The query so far (it fails at the FOR statement)

```
SELECT * FROM  
(
    SELECT
        PT.ParentPart,
        ACT.AC,
        WCT.WC,
        PT.ActFin 
    FROM @ProductionTable AS PT
        INNER JOIN @WCTable AS WCT ON WCT.WC = PT.WC
        INNER JOIN @ACTable AS ACT ON PT.AC = ACT.AC
) t
PIVOT(
    COUNT(CASE
            WHEN
                PT.ActFin > '2019-11-06' --count
            THEN
                1
            END)
    FOR ACT.AC IN ( --this is where things fall apart
        '54',
        '53',
        '52')
)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: "this is where things fall apart" won't help us help you.  Fall apart how?  Error out?  Wrong result?  No result?

Comment: I simply don't know how to proceed from this point.

Comment: So what's wrong with your current code?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "I don't see any `FOR` statement".

Comment: @alexherm FOR ACT.AC IN (...

Comment: @Eric I'm using an in-house T-SQL program, it tells me it fails in the FOR statement and nothing more.

Comment: What happen if you replace `ACT.AC` with `t.AC`?

Comment: `ACT` and `PT` don't exist in outer query since you rename it with `t`.

Comment: hmm good idea. Sadly I left work sometime ago, so I'll try this in the morning first thing, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns in the `FOR` clause need to be wrapped in `[]`:

```
SELECT * FROM  
(
    SELECT
        PT.ParentPart,
        ACT.AC,
        WCT.WC,
        PT.ActFin 
    FROM @ProductionTable AS PT
        INNER JOIN @WCTable AS WCT ON WCT.WC = PT.WC
        INNER JOIN @ACTable AS ACT ON PT.AC = ACT.AC
) t
PIVOT(
    COUNT(CASE
            WHEN
                PT.ActFin > '2019-11-06' --count
            THEN
                1
            END)
    FOR ACT.AC IN ( --this is where things fall apart
        [54],
        [53],
        [52])
)
```